# running a bottle app from mod_wsgi handle results in maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Tags: python, mod-wsgi, bottle, openshift

I'm getting a strange "RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object" from my bottle app. while running it from a wsgi handle (inside a virtualenv) in **openshift** paas service.

the traceback doesn't offer me a clue about what's wrong

I should also mention that running the bottle script straight on my dev maching (e.g python pythonapp.py) does work properly.

**edit:** In order to verify this problem is connected to running bottle with mod_wsgi I installed it on my dev computer. running straight python works. running with mod_wsgi gives me this strange RuntimeError **end of edit**

I saw in issue [#201](https://github.com/defnull/bottle/commit/882668ff342e89d6d91fb4138b8546632946d571)
that this problem was already "solved" but probably for another use case

I'm using bottle 0.10.9 on python 2.6 in a linux server

```
Critical error while processing request: /about
Error: RuntimeError('maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object',)
Traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "path/to/app/virtenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/bottle-0.10.9-py2.6.egg/bottle.py",
line 824, in wsgi
    out = self._cast(self._handle(environ), request, response)

File "path/to/app/virtenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/bottle-0.10.9-py2.6.egg/bottle.py",
line 780, in _cast
    return self._cast(out, request, response)


File "path/to/app/virtenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/bottle-0.10.9-py2.6.egg/bottle.py",
line 780, in _cast
    return self._cast(out, request, response)

File "path/to/app/virtenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/bottle-0.10.9-py2.6.egg/bottle.py",
line 780, in _cast
    return self._cast(out, request, response)

File "path/to/app/virtenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/bottle-0.10.9-py2.6.egg/bottle.py",
line 780, in _cast
    return self._cast(out, request, response)

File "path/to/app/virtenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/bottle-0.10.9-py2.6.egg/bottle.py",
line 780, in _cast
    return self._cast(out, request, response)

File "path/to/app/virtenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/bottle-0.10.9-py2.6.egg/bottle.py",
line 780, in _cast
    return self._cast(out, request, response)

File "path/to/app/virtenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/bottle-0.10.9-py2.6.egg/bottle.py",
line 780, in _cast
    return self._cast(out, request, response)

File "path/to/app/virtenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/bottle-0.10.9-py2.6.egg/bottle.py",
line 780, in _cast
    return self._cast(out, request, response)

File "path/to/app/virtenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/bottle-0.10.9-py2.6.egg/bottle.py",
line 780, in _cast
    return self._cast(out, request, response)
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

The WSGI handle:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import sys
here = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))


try:
    os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = os.path.join(os.environ['OPENSHIFT_APP_DIR'],'virtenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages')

except:
    os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = os.path.join(here,'..','data/virtenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages')

print ('python egg cache set to: %s' % os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'])
try:

    virtualenv = os.path.join(os.environ['OPENSHIFT_APP_DIR'],"virtenv/bin/activate_this.py")
except:
    virtualenv = os.path.join(here,'..',"data/virtenv/bin/activate_this.py")

print ('virtualenv is in:%s' % virtualenv)
try:
    execfile(virtualenv, dict(__file__=virtualenv))
    print ('executed')
    sys.path.append(here)

except IOError:
    pass

from myapp import application
```

the myapp.py file:

```
#!/bin/usr/env python
#-*- coding:UTF-8 -*-

from bottle import route,run, view, error, static_file, debug, url, redirect, request, response,  default_app

from wikifetch import init_db,load_session,Wikilink, statistic, wiki_populate
import bottle
from sqlalchemy.exc import StatementError
#from config import production_port, production_server
import json
debug(True)
bottle.TEMPLATE_PATH.append("./views")

init_db()
session = load_session()
try:
    stats = statistic()
except:
    print ("no data yet")
    pass

@route('/wsgi')
def show_ip():
    env = request.environ
    for k,v in env.items():
        print k,": ",v
    return env

@route()
def default():
    redirect("/monitor")

@route(["/monitor","/index","/"])
@view("monitor")
def monitor():
    title = request.query.title
    page = request.query.page or 0
    page = int(page)
    try:
        total = stats[0]
        all = session.query(Wikilink).filter(Wikilink.title.like('%'+ title +'%')).count()
        monitor = session.query(Wikilink).order_by('title').filter(Wikilink.title.like('%'+ title +'%')).offset(page*20).limit(20).all() #filter(Wikilink.id>(page*20))
        #print "page=",page," title=",title,
    except StatementError:
        session.rollback()
        #session.begin()

    #print monitor
    return dict(monitor=monitor,pages=(all/20),number=all,total = total)

@route("/why")
@view("why")
def why():
    return dict()

@route("/about")
@view("about")
def about():
    return dict()

@route("/learned")
@view("learned")
def learned():
    return dict()



@route("/stats")
@view("stats")
def statistic():
    return dict(stats= stats)

@route ("/static/<filepath:path>", name="static")
def static(filepath):
    #print 'yey', filepath
    return static_file(filepath,root = "./static/")


@error(404)
def error404(error):
    return static_file('404.html',root="./static")

#@error(502)
@error(500)
def error500(error):
    return static_file('500.html', root = "./static")

application = default_app()

if __name__ =='__main__':
    from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server #using the builtin wsgi server
    httpd = make_server('localhost', 8052, application)
```

I would be glad for any debugging clue.

**edit:** I tried setting the recursion limit lower but that just fails other things (path.append, sqlalchemy etc..) when I rise above the level that other things fail (37 to be precise) then I get this error message. when I tailed the error log I was able to produce another 2 lines that go before the error stack:

```
[Mon Mar 26 14:50:52 2012] [error] no data yet #if you look in the code above - means that wikiwatch.py file passed the first 'stats' function

[Mon Mar 26 14:50:52 2012] [error] /home/usrname/workspace/appname/data/virtenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/bottle.py:824: DeprecationWarning: Error handlers must not return :exc:`HTTPResponse`.
[Mon Mar 26 14:50:52 2012] [error]   out = self._cast(self._handle(environ), request, response)
```

Comment: Set the recursion limit much lower so that we can see what's calling that.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams tried that, doesn't seem to be very usefull but postes it as an edit.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is triggering the error handler, and it seems that the handler is raising another error.

Since it works without the wsgi handler, it's probably a paths issue that is triggering the initial error. You can try dissabling the error handlers to see the bottle error page, which may shed some light on the issue.

Reguarding  the error raised within the handler i noticed that in the `static()` function, you use the keyword argument `root="./static/"` whereas in the error handlers you omitted the trailing slash.

Comment: I disabled the error handlers but given the same errorpage.. I don't think the error handlers are the issue. could you eloberate on what kind of paths error should I be checking?

Comment: @alonisser just the contents of sys.path, are the modules you import accessible. your wsgi handler sets the path, with `sys.path.append(here)`, and also by invoking the virtualenv activate script. you can try running the wsgi handler directly like you did your pythonapp.py script. just add the same `if __name__ == '__main__':` block to the end of wsgi.py (or whatever the name is) and run `python wsgi.py`. That sould be the same as running the script directly, but with the paths set by the wsgi handler.